# Cloud datastore order by with ancestor

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Language: NodeJS

Is it possible to combine both an **order** and **ancestorKey** when querying google cloud data?

Something similar to this:

```
const ancestorKey = datastore.key({namespace: 'MyNameSpace', 
                                   path: ['MyParentEntity', 'parent_entity_id']});

const query = datastore.createQuery('MyNameSpace', 'my_child_entity')
                        .order('someProperty', {descending: true})
                        .hasAncestor(ancestorKey);
```

NOTE: The above doesn't work

Comment: define `doesn't work`

Comment: Quite right Dan - apologies to the lazy information of 'doesn't work' - I'll get the error I received added to the ticket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: Yes, this is possible.**

Through the [API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/), at least, this kind of query is possible.

Example:

1. First we create the ancestor entity (keep the key ID from the response). [[API call]](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/datastore/v1/datastore.projects.commit?projectId=YOUR-PROJECT-ID&_h=2&resource=%257B%250A%20%20%2522mutations%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522insert%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522key%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522partitionId%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522projectId%2522%253A%20%2522YOUR-PROJECT-ID%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522namespaceId%2522%253A%20%2522ancestor-order%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522path%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522kind%2522%253A%20%2522ancestor%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522properties%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522name%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522stringValue%2522%253A%20%2522ancerstor%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%255D%252C%250A%20%20%2522mode%2522%253A%20%2522NON_TRANSACTIONAL%2522%250A%257D&)
2. Then we create a couple of child entities. API calls: [[1]](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/datastore/v1/datastore.projects.commit?projectId=YOUR-PROJECT-ID&_h=1&resource=%257B%250A%20%20%2522mutations%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522insert%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522key%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522partitionId%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522projectId%2522%253A%20%2522YOUR-PROJECT-ID%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522namespaceId%2522%253A%20%2522ancestor-order%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522path%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522kind%2522%253A%20%2522ancestor%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522id%2522%253A%20%2522ANCESTOR-KEY-ID%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522kind%2522%253A%20%2522child%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522properties%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522name%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522stringValue%2522%253A%20%2522child%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522order%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522integerValue%2522%253A%20%25221%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%255D%252C%250A%20%20%2522mode%2522%253A%20%2522NON_TRANSACTIONAL%2522%250A%257D&) [[2]](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/datastore/v1/datastore.projects.commit?projectId=YOUR-PROJECT-ID&_h=1&resource=%257B%250A%20%20%2522mutations%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522insert%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522key%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522partitionId%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522projectId%2522%253A%20%2522YOUR-PROJECT-ID%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522namespaceId%2522%253A%20%2522ancestor-order%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522path%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522kind%2522%253A%20%2522ancestor%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522id%2522%253A%20%2522ANCESTOR-KEY-ID%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522kind%2522%253A%20%2522child%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522properties%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522name%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522stringValue%2522%253A%20%2522child%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522order%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522integerValue%2522%253A%20%25222%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%255D%252C%250A%20%20%2522mode%2522%253A%20%2522NON_TRANSACTIONAL%2522%250A%257D&)
3. For [Datastore queries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries) you'll need an index for each property or combination of properties that you want to query. [Datastore provides built-in single-property indexes by default](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes), but your query is composite (ancestor+order_property), so you'll have to build your own indexes. To do so, first write your `index.yaml` file (I'm creating two indexes, one for ordering ascending and another for descending):

   ```
   indexes:
   - kind: child
     ancestor: yes
     properties:
       - name: order
         direction: desc

   - kind: child
     ancestor: yes
     properties:
       - name: order
         direction: asc
   ```
4. Deploy your indexes with `gcloud datastore create-indexes index.yaml`
5. Wait for the indexes to finish building, and then you can perform the query. API calls: [[ascending]](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/datastore/v1/datastore.projects.runQuery?projectId=YOUR-PROJECT-ID&_h=1&resource=%257B%250A%20%20%2522partitionId%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%2522projectId%2522%253A%20%2522YOUR-PROJECT-ID%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%2522namespaceId%2522%253A%20%2522ancestor-order%2522%250A%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%2522query%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%2522kind%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522name%2522%253A%20%2522child%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%255D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%2522order%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522property%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522name%2522%253A%20%2522order%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522direction%2522%253A%20%2522DESCENDING%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%255D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%2522filter%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522propertyFilter%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522op%2522%253A%20%2522HAS_ANCESTOR%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522value%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522keyValue%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522path%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522kind%2522%253A%20%2522ancestor%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522id%2522%253A%20%2522ANCESTOR-KEY-ID%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522partitionId%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522namespaceId%2522%253A%20%2522ancestor-order%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522projectId%2522%253A%20%2522YOUR-PROJECT-ID%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522property%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522name%2522%253A%20%2522__key__%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%257D%250A%257D&) [[descending]](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/datastore/v1/datastore.projects.runQuery?projectId=YOUR-PROJECT-ID&_h=1&resource=%257B%250A%20%20%2522partitionId%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%2522projectId%2522%253A%20%2522YOUR-PROJECT-ID%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%2522namespaceId%2522%253A%20%2522ancestor-order%2522%250A%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%2522query%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%2522kind%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522name%2522%253A%20%2522child%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%255D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%2522order%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522property%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522name%2522%253A%20%2522order%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522direction%2522%253A%20%2522DESCENDING%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%255D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%2522filter%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522propertyFilter%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522op%2522%253A%20%2522HAS_ANCESTOR%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522value%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522keyValue%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522path%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522kind%2522%253A%20%2522ancestor%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522id%2522%253A%20%2522ANCESTOR-KEY-ID%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522partitionId%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522namespaceId%2522%253A%20%2522ancestor-order%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522projectId%2522%253A%20%2522YOUR-PROJECT-ID%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522property%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522name%2522%253A%20%2522__key__%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%257D%250A%257D&)

You can test this example in the [cloud shell](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudshell/open?page=shell&tutorial=ancestor-order.md&git_repo=https://gist.github.com/e754e03989972beefa86c979e4c60bab.git).

Knowing that the API works properly, you just have to implement this in the [idiomatic library](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/datastore/1.3.x/). Make sure you have your entities properly defined, and your indexes created. If you have doubts, just try your query through the API to verify if it should work within node or not.